# How to work with angular 2 profile for grails

Tags: grails, angular

it's great news that Grails 3.2.1 now comes with an Angular2 profile, but I don't know how to use it.

The profile description tells me that there should be the standard command like `create-domain-class`, but when I create an app through

`grails create-app test-ng --profile angular2`

I get a working angular2 project, but it even seems that this project is not recognized as grails app. When I enter the grails cli, I only get the commands like `create-app` which are available outside of projects.

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: This is hours old, SO is probably not the best place for this topic yet :)  The [Grails slack](http://slack-signup.grails.org/) is quite active but probably migrating to the new [Groovy slack](https://groovycommunity.com/), but either of those are probably your best bet.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Nowadays this layout is called "multi-project". Separate 4 the client and server applications. To make things easier, the tasks test, `integrationTest`, and `bootRun` have been created in the client application to make executing those tasks easier across the whole application.

Since `Gradle` executes tasks synchronously, and the `bootRun` task will never finish, it is important to execute it in parallel. At the root of the project:

```
./gradlew bootRun --parallel
```

Opening things also separately by 2 instances of your IDE or preferred text processor.

see the [docs](https://docs.gradle.org/current/userguide/multi_project_builds.html)

Answer (score 4):

your *grails create-app test-ng --profile angular2*
command should have created three folders in your *test-ng*-project-folder:

- client
- gradle
- server

change to *server* and start *grails* command

now you should have the wellknown grails project.
but i am still on the first steps of examining the new grails-profile. so i hope i could help you.

Comment: How do you deploy a war with this that contains the correctly placed client files?

Answer (score 2):

```
grails list-profiles
```

show list of available profiles, I suggest you use this because for example now angular2 profile is angular and angular1 is angularJS.